# How to create a smooth CSS cutout for a modal

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a smooth cutout similar to the image below.

[image]

I have been able to achieve something similar using

```css
  -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(
    circle at top,
    transparent 30px,
    black 31px
  ) !important;
```

But it is not as smooth as I want it to be. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-wavy-shapes-patterns-in-css/

Comment: It does help. I’ll carefully go through it.  Thanks a lot